# angular 2 select set selected item

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I have a `select` in Angular 2

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
 <option [ngValue]="'<empty>'"></option>
 <option *ngFor="let e of range" [ngValue]="e.value">{{e.display}}</option>
</select>
```

Note that there is an "empty" option at the top. Every time the user selects an option I want to process the selected item **and then set the first, empty option as selected**. I've tried adding an `(change)` and `ngModelChange` handler and can set `selectedItem` to whatever value I want, **but that doesn't change the displayed selected option**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (ngModelChange)="processSelectedItem();selectedItem = range[0]">
```

You can also move `selectedItem = range[0]` into `processSelectedItem() { ... }`

Comment: You could try to inject `private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef` and then in `processSelected() { /* process */; this.selectedItem = null; this.cdRef.detectChanges(); this.selectItem = this.range[0]; /* this.cdRef.detectChanges(); */}`. Setting a value back to its previous value confuses change detection. With this code change detection should be able to pick it up. Not sure if the commented out 2nd `detectChanges()` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks alot, using `ChangeDetectorRef` solved the problem.